# Difference between 「移行」and 「移動」

Tags: word-choice

> 「移行」
>
> 「移動」

What is usage difference between these two words.
Many times not able to judge why one of those used and not the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

移動 basically refers to physical movements.
移行 means changing to new system, to new stage, to another state. Or you also use 移行 when something metaphysical moves (e.g. popularity, interest, point of discussion...)

So if I translate, it would be

> 移動 = to move
>   移行 = transition, shift

The typical usages for 移行 are

> 新制度に移行する
>   (=change to new system)
>
> 私の会社はWindowsからMacに移行した。
>   (=The company I work in stopped using Windows and start using Mac.)
>
> 若者たちの興味は、クレープからパンケーキに移行しつつある。
>   (=What young people are interested in is shifting from crepes to pancakes.)

移動 is a very basic word for "movement".

> イタリアからフランスへ飛行機で移動する
>   (=go to France from Italy by plane)
>
> ここは危険なので、早くここから移動しましょう。
>   (=It's dangerous here so let's leave here soon.)
>
> ファイルをデスクトップ・フォルダに移動する
>   (=move a file to Desktop folder)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following might be helpful, although I could be 100% wrong in my assessment on the word meanings from looking at what similar words were defined as.

> 「移行」refers to movement or action over a period of time or state of change,
>
> while 「移動」refers to or has something to do with physical movement.

I'm not very confident in my own assessment though, seeing as how I'm not very fluent in Japanese. I got the above possible meanings from typing 移行 and「移動」into https://jisho.org/search/ then figuring out what each individual search result had in common with other suggested definitions from that particular search.